# Converting mouse coordinates for ui in world space

Tags: unity-game-engine

Im having problems with position convertions. The way im trying to solve it may be very wrong but thats due to inexperience in that case and im up for any suggestion on how to do it differently.

What im trying to do is a gui with a dot graph envelope that the user can change by draging the dots with the mouse.

This is what i would wan it to look like.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvvFW.jpg

First i did the UI like normal in overlay but i couldnt get the line renderer to work so i took the whole ui into world space. This makes the line renderer visible. With the UI in world space ive tried both to put the envelope line renderer in the canvas with the rest of the ui and outside the canvas UI.

Here is the code that renders the lines where the dots are and moves the dots when the mouse drags them :

```
    public class Envelope : MonoBehaviour
{
 
    LineRenderer lineRenderer;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        lineRenderer = GetComponentInChildren<LineRenderer>();
        
    }
 
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        var points = GetComponentsInChildren<EnvelopePoint>().Select(ep => ep.transform.localPosition).ToArray();
        lineRenderer.positionCount = points.Length;
        lineRenderer.SetPositions(points);
    }
}
 
 
 
public class EnvelopePoint : MonoBehaviour
{
 
    [SerializeField] bool isHeld = false;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
 
    }
 
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (isHeld)
        {
//            Vector3 mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            Vector3 mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
            transform.position = mousePos;
        }
    }
 
    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        isHeld = true;
    }
 
    private void OnMouseUp()
    {
        isHeld = false;
    }
}
```

The best result is to put the envelope outside of the canvas.

The lines render well to where the points are but im not able to convert the mouse position to correct coordinates for the dots. When i click on a dot to drag it the dot snaps to a position a bit lower and a bit to the left of the mouse. Like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/42R39.jpg

But then i can drag the dots and the lines adjust perfectly.

I guess i have two questions:

How should i get the mouse position conversion correctly?

Is this a strange or over complicated way of doing this? Is there a more reasonable way?

Id love some tip as well on what i should read up on to better understand the different screen types and how to convert between them.

Answer (score 0):

[RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToWorldPointInRectangle](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToWorldPointInRectangle.html): *Transform a screen space point to a position in world space that is on the plane of the given RectTransform.*

There is also ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle but since you are modifying Line Renderer's points (which are in world space), I think ScreenPointToWorldPointInRectangle best suits your needs.

Comment: Im not sure i follow how to do this but i change the update method to the following but it isnt working: 

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (isHeld)
        {
            Vector2 mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            if (RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToWorldPointInRectangle(GetComponent<RectTransform>(), 
                Input.mousePosition, Camera.main, out Vector3 wp))
            {
                transform.position = wp;
            
            }
                }
    }

Comment: That looks correct, strange. Then you can try calling ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle with parent Transform's RectTransform and then setting anchoredPosition to the *out localPoint* parameter.